# Boton que su accion click cambie el valor de un label, me devuelve ([object HTMLInputElement]), por algo escrito en una casilla de texto

Tags: javascript, html

```
        function addLoadEvent() {  
    var nombre1 = document.getElementById("lbltipAddedComment");
    var nombre2 = document.getElementById("lbltipAddedComment2");
        nombre1 .innerHTML=nombre2 ;
};

       <html><body><label id="lbltipAddedComment">Nombre</label>
       <input type="text" id="lbltipAddedComment2">
       <button id="lbltipAddedComment3" onclick="addLoadEvent()"</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La siguiente función te puede servir, utilizando `JQuery` obtienes el valor del `label` y del `input` por medio de su `id`, se le asigna el valor del `input` al `label` cada vez que hagas `click` en el botón:

```js
function addLoadEvent() {  
    var nombre1 = $('#lbltipAddedComment').text();
    var nombre2 = $('#lbltipAddedComment2').val();
    
    $('#lbltipAddedComment').text(nombre2);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
     <label id="lbltipAddedComment">Nombre</label>
     <input type="text" id="lbltipAddedComment2">
     <button id="lbltipAddedComment3" onclick="addLoadEvent()">Click!</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Te comento que tu código no funcionaba debido a que lo que debes obtener del `label` es el texto por medio del `textContent` y del `input` no estás obteniendo el `valor` por medio del `.value` .

Te dejo el código sin JQuery por si lo necesitas:

```js
function addLoadEvent() {  
    var nombre1 = document.getElementById("lbltipAddedComment").textContent;
    var nombre2 = document.getElementById("lbltipAddedComment2").value;
    
    document.getElementById("lbltipAddedComment").textContent = nombre2;
};
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
     <label id="lbltipAddedComment">Nombre</label>
     <input type="text" id="lbltipAddedComment2">
     <button id="lbltipAddedComment3" onclick="addLoadEvent()">Click!</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Espero te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: Por nada, suerte compañero.